# Bias and variance for quantile estimates

Tags: regression, quantiles, bias-variance-tradeoff

Is bias variance tradeoff a thing for quartile regression? Can I assume the error for quantile estimation follows a certain distribution (e.g., estimated quantile - true quantile follows normal distribution)?

Comment: Two wildly different questions. You might pick one or the other and provide more details about why you are interested.